# having Error:BrokenCount>0

Tags: installation, apt, software-center, package-management, pidgin

I was installing pidginfacebookchat-1.69.deb package from a 3rd party "https://code.google.com/p/pidgin-facebookchat/" but after installing it from the Ubuntu Software Center, an error appeared **Items cannot be installed or removed until package catalog is removed** even after pressing repair the same error keeps appearing.

```
sudo apt-get check shows 
*You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 pidgin-data : Breaks: pidgin-facebookchat (< 1.69-2) but 1.69 is installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f*.</pre>
```

`sudo apt-get -f install` is showing:

```
*dpkg: warning: there's no installed package matching pidgin-facebookchat:amd64*
```

can somebody please help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get rid of the 3rd party package. The folks who compiled the package version 1.69 that is provided for download at google code site did a poor job. That package breaks .deb packaging standards in several ways.

pidgin-data version 1:2.10.7-0ubuntu4.1 which is installed on Raring by default and that triggers the error, explicitly states in its control that it `Breaks: pidgin-facebookchat (<< 1.69-2)` which you were trying to install (1.69). That fact is reflected in the error message you get. Pidgin-data's package control also states that it `Replaces: pidgin-facebookchat (<< 1.69-2)` which means that it replaces some files from the `pidgin-facebookchat` package you try to install, i.e. there is a clear conflict.

Since the 3rd party packages is broken there is no trivial way to straighten this up, **except** *luckily there is an Ubuntu packaged version 1.69-2.1ubuntu1*.

ACTION:

1. Get rid of the 3rd party package.
2. Install the Ubuntu package provided by the default channel.
3. Repair the dpkg system on the go if needed.

That should be done by simply ...

```
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install pidgin-facebookchat
```

*Maybe* you need to remove the faulty package with `dpkg -r pidgin-facebookchat` first. Also some `dpkg --configure -a`, `apt-get -f install` could be needed. But just the two lines above should do it. If your dpkg system got too much confused, additional investigation may be needed.

CONCLUSION:

When you find a fancy software package, first look after versions provided by the channels provided by Ubuntu or a PPA. Chances are that packages out of the wild break your system. ;)

Comment: Thanx a ton, worked like charm